# What is the memory map section in RISCV

Tags: memory, operating-system, cpu, riscv, mmu

I'm familiar with MIPS architecture, and I've known that MIPS has memory section such as kseg0, kseg1. Which determine whether the segment can be cached or mapped. For example, you should locate some I/O devices(like UART) to the uncached segment.

But I didn't find anything related in RISCV arch. So how does the RISCV OS know the address should be mapped or not?

By the way: I know the value in satp CSR desrcibes the translation mode. When OS is running, the value must set other than "Bare(disabled MMU)" so that the OS can support the virtual memory. So if CPU access UART address, the value in satp is still not "Bare"? But it should be "Bare"?

Comment: mips has a lot of things that are the exception rather than the rule.  Normally you use an MMU which would be somewhere outside the core itself.  sifive has a linux capable chip so you can look at how they implemented it.  the expectation is there will be some number of cores out there and some number of chip vendors using these cores and the implementations can/should vary.

Comment: RISCV OS makes no sense, riscv is an architecture that can be turned into cores that can have chips built around them and those chips can run any number of operating systems (infinite actually, depends on how many people and how much time spent per OS).

Comment: Like ARM the risc-v foundation may choose to define things outside the instruction set and core like an mmu so that for example linux porting isnt a nightmare (like it has been for ARM).  You will see in the arm architecture documents the MMU interface, (L1) cache, etc are documented/defined.  Will see how this all plays out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RISC-V is a family of instruction sets, ranging from MCU style processors that have no memory-mapping and no memory protection mechanisms (Physical Memory Protection is optional).

From your question, I assume you are talking about processors that support User and Supervisor level ISA, as documented in the RISC-V privileged spec.

It sounds like you want a spec describing which physical addresses are cacheable. Looking at the list of CSRs, I believe this information is not in the CSRs because it is platform specific. In systems I've worked with, it is either hard-coded in platform drivers or passed via device-tree.

For Linux, the device-tree entries are not RISC-V specific: there are device tree entries specifying the physical address range of memory. Additionally, each I/O device would have a device tree entry specifying its physical address range.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not very familiar with dtb, I will take a look at it.

Comment: Device tree syntax is architecture independent, but its grammar is architecture and device specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the RISC-V privileged spec ([The RISC-V Instruction Set Manual Volume II: Privileged Architecture](https://content.riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/riscv-privileged-v1.10.pdf) 3.5 Physical Memory Attributes).

"For RISC-V, we separate out specification and checking of PMAs into a separate hardware structure, the PMA checker. In many cases, the attributes are known at system design time for each physical address region, and can be hardwired into the PMA checker. Where the attributes are run-time configurable, platform-specific memory-mapped control registers can be provided to specify these attributes at a granularity appropriate to each region on the platform (e.g., for an on-chip SRAM that can be flexibly divided between cacheable and uncacheable uses)"

I think if you want to check non-cacheable or cacheable in RISCV, you need to design a PMA unit that provide MMU to check memory attribute.